# Export dataframe from R to Excel, while preserving old data on excel file

Tags: r, excel, export-to-excel, export-to-csv

I'm using the write.xlsx command to export my dataframe in R to excel. 
e.g.
`write.xlsx(output, "C:/myfolder/output.xlsx)`
The dataframe has 4 columns. The data in these columns gets updated weekly. I want to export the dataframe in R to an excel file without losing the old data I had from the previous week.

Basically, exporting the data to an excel file should help keep a log of the data week on week

Comment: Read the old file, `rbind()` the new data, write the new file?

Answer (score 0):

You can write each week's data to a separate worksheet within the same workbook using `XLConnect` package.

```
library(XLConnect)
dat <- loadWorkbook(filename="yourDataFile.xlsx") # read existing file
createSheet(dat, name = "weekNumber") # create worksheet for the current week
writeWorksheet(dat,
               sheet = "weekNumber",
               data = yourDataframe,
               header = FALSE,
               rownames = NULL) # write yourDataframe to the new worksheet
saveWorkbook(dat) # save the new worksheet
```